# V7 SearchView and RxBinding

Tags: android, rx-java, searchview, rx-android

How do we go about using the `RxBinding` for `SearchView` within an Android app. I currently have the following in my presenter:

```
RxSearchView.queryTextChangeEvents(searchView).debounce(400,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).
            observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
            subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()).
            skip(2).
            map(searchViewQueryTextEvent -> searchViewQueryTextEvent.queryText().toString()).
            flatMap(s -> RestWebClient.get().getSearchedGifs(s,"dczC")).
            subscribe(OnNextAction,onErrorAction);



Action1<GifsData> OnNextAction = gifsData -> mainFragmentPresenterInterface.displaySearchedGifsList(gifsData);

Action1<Throwable> onErrorAction = throwable -> Log.d("#######",throwable.getMessage());
```

For some reason though the `queryTextChangeEvents` never gets fired whenever i try searching for something from the `searchView`. 
The above snippet is being triggered from the `onPrepareOptionsMenu` from within a fragment.
Is that the right place to establish the `subscription`? Can any one point out what is the issue here?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting anything printed in logcat because of onErrorAction?

Comment: No errors were logged

Comment: I had the same issue earlier but i solved it by creating two different obsevables. You can refer that [here](https://github.com/muraliprajapati/RxJavaProject/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/murali/rxjavaproject/MainActivity.java)

Comment: @user2511882 Did you manage to solve this issue? I 'm running into the same thing now.

Comment: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()